# numpy/scipy: fill upper triangle of array with elements of 1d vector?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Say I have a flattened 1D vector that exactly corresponds to the upper triangle elements of a 2D array.

The 1D vector needs to be read into the upper triangle.

I might do the following in python:

```
triu_flat = ...
row,col = np.triu_indices(50)

D = np.zeros((50,50))

i=0 
for r in row: 
    for c in col:
        D[r,c] = triu_flat[i]
        i++
```

However, there must be a way to do this via numpy/scipy operations.

Comment: You can get the corresponding indices for upper triangle using [`np.triu_indices`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.triu_indices.html) then just do an assignment.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can simply use the indices returned by `triu_indices()`, no need for a `for` loop:

```
import numpy

data = numpy.arange(6)
out = numpy.zeros((3, 3))
inds = numpy.triu_indices(len(out))
out[inds] = data
```